# Is it possible to extend .net framework namespace like one can extend .net framework class?

Tags: c#

It is possible to extend a class like string (see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/extendingstringclass03162008132109pm/extendingstringclass.aspx) is there a way to extend in a similar way System.Web for example by adding our own classes to this namespace ?

Comment: Unless I am totally misunderstanding you, can't you just create a class using the namespace "System.Web"?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: System.Web was just an example. Maybe useful if you have a third-party assembly with some types (Invoice, Contact) and you want to create a Typed Collection for these entities, and therefore it might seem to make sense to locate these new collections in the same namespace for convenience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. Try something like this:

```
namespace System.Web
{
   public class ThisIsMyAdditionToSystemWeb
   {
   }
}
```

But obviously, this will not add anything to the actual .Net assemblies, projects that want to utilize your "extension" will have to reference your assembly.

Comment: So there is no "sealed" namespace :)

Comment: VS will report all kinds of errors (will not find the classes you injected in System), even though the code will compile flawlessly

Comment: @RaduSimionescu - oh? works like a charm on my machine ;) care to share code and errors? perhaps raise a new question here on SO..

Comment: @PeterLillevold it's ok, I just ignored the errors. Its probably just an ide bug that I am experiencing.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, sure, a namespace is not tied to any particular assembly.  It is otherwise an excellent way to confuse the user of your classes beyond recoverable hope.  And *strongly* discouraged by Microsoft, they claim both "Microsoft" and "System" as theirs.  With zero sympathy if some kind of future update of .NET will have a namespace name that collides with yours.

Comment: Right. You can do it. Congrats! Just don't. Please, please don't.

Comment: Not related to the question, but Hans, I think you sleep less than the famed automaton Jon Skeet.

Comment: Well said you're right but why would it would more collide than with method extensions ? If I extend a .NET framework Class with a method and Microsoft decided to use that same method name in some future there would also be collision am I wrong ?

Comment: @user - there's a difference, an extension method is made on an *existing* class.  They'll add new namespaces and not think anything of it, adding new methods to existing classes isn't very common.

Comment: Hmmm... suppose you want to create IsNullOrEmpty extension method on `Guid` and `Nullable<Guid>`, so you don't have to compare it against `Guid.Empty` all the time.  You'd want that method to be available everywhere `Guid` is available, so wouldn't it make sense to just put your `GuidExtensions` class in the `System` namespace?  One could always give the class a unique prefix, since such an extension class will never be directly referenced in code.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind not using other, "Microsoft-reserved" namespaces, but lately I've been writing a lot of P/Invoke code in .NET, and sometimes it's simply to add functionality to .NET that I'm surprised doesn't already exist.

For example, CopyFileEx provides file copy ability whilst leveraging system resources (e.g. DMA) and can report progress--something .NET does not. In making my own namespaces that mimic .NET's (System.*), I end up with namespace ambiguity, and that's frustrating.

I feel like adding CopyFileEx to System.IO.File would be a good use of this.

Answer (score 2):

The example linked in the question is using [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to extend the sealed string class. There is nothing stopping you from writing extension methods for any class.

And as others have said, extending a Namespace is as simple as declaring that namespace when creating a new object. Just be sure to consider the implications before you do it.

Comment: Adding symbols to somebody else's namespace is rude, can cause many hard to diagnose build breaks or unexpected run-time behaviors, and may violate copyright, trademark or license restrictions. If you need to add something to somebody else's namespace, issue a PR to their repo or use extension methods within your own namespace.